# Convert csv to json using powershell

Tags: powershell

I have a csv file and when I convert it using convertto-json i am getting the following error

> ConvertTo-Json : The converted JSON string is in bad format. At line:1
>   char:70
>   + Get-Content -path E:\test.csv | ConvertFrom-Csv -Delimiter ',' | ConvertTo-J ...
>   +                                                                      ~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (@{name=WebError.Show; data=1}:PSObject) [ConvertTo-Json],
>   InvalidOperationException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : JsonStringInBadFormat,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ConvertToJsonCommand

when i use -compress with convertto-json i am getting the output, but its a compressed json version which is ugly to see, is there a better way to convert this csv to json or is there a way to decompress the json

**CSV:**

```
name,data
Play,http://{gho}.domain.com/
BDomain,domain.com
Charts,2
Compress,0
CompressJ,0
WebError.Show,1
```

**Compressed Json Output:**

```
[{"name":"Play","data":"http://{gho}.domain.com/"},{"name":"BDomain","data":"domain.com"},{"name":"Charts","data":"2"},{"name":"Compress","data":"0"},{"name":"CompressJ"
,"data":"0"}]
```

Comment: Please share your JSON with us. We need a reproducable example in order to help you.

Comment: Why are you piping a `Get-Content` into a `ConvertFrom-Csv`? Would it not be easier to use `Import-Csv`?

Comment: edited the question with csv and json files

Answer (score 0):

I don't seem to have any issues using ConvertFrom-Csv and ConvertTo-Json with your example string.

Using:

```
"name,data
Play,http://{gho}.domain.com/
BDomain,domain.com
Charts,2
Compress,0
CompressJ,0" | ConvertFrom-Csv | ConvertTo-Json
```

Gives me:

```
[
    {
        "name":  "Play",
        "data":  "http://{gho}.domain.com/"
    },
    {
        "name":  "BDomain",
        "data":  "domain.com"
    },
    {
        "name":  "Charts",
        "data":  "2"
    },
    {
        "name":  "Compress",
        "data":  "0"
    },
    {
        "name":  "CompressJ",
        "data":  "0"
    }
]
```

Could you post the PowerShell code which is giving you the error?

Comment: i have this as a file and using import-csv / get-item , both gives the same error

Comment: get-content..sorry

Comment: When i have a dotted value, it throws this error, WebError.Show, any workaround?

Comment: Sorry I don't get the same error when reading from a file, executing `Get-Content "test.csv"  | ConvertFrom-Csv | ConvertTo-Json` works fine.

`Import-Csv "test.csv" | ConvertTo-Json` is also fine for me.

Comment: OMG :-o actually this csv was generated from an excel file by using save as, could be some problem there?

Comment: I'm not sure, I just tried saving the same data to a CSV using Excel and it still works fine. If you copy your above sample to a text file and using that file does it work correctly?

Answer (score 0):

```
Import-Csv $File | Convertto-Json
```

This may work for you.

Comment: it throws the error when it has to parse WebError.Show

Answer (score 0):

Powershell command below creates `OUTPUTFILE.json` format file from the `INPUTFILE.csv` file format:

```
import-csv .\INPUTFILE.csv | ConvertTo-Json -depth 100 | Out-File .\OUTPUTFILE.json
```